# How many comments I have posted - Is this info found somewhere?

Tags: support, comments

We can find how many months we are a member for, I can even see for how many days I have visited the site.

Besides that, I can also see how many questions/answers I have posted, how many posts I have edited, how many helpful flags I have raised, how many votes I have cast. But what about my comments count?

Commenting is also one of the activities. So, is this info found somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way is to click:

> [any profile] > Activity > all actions > **comments**

See below:

[image]

Comment: Why the spoiler block?

Comment: BTW @iammilind did you already know that one can chk the number of comments like that or you searched for it only after seeing my question?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, because the latest comments were about Kamasutra/sex etc. So it was not looking right. To, Rickross, I already knew, due to exploration of the profile page long time back.

Comment: I think it will not include deleted comments